# sumar en caso de que se cumpla una condición

Tags: sql, datatables, jquery-validate

Estoy creando un query donde me están solicitando sumar las cantidades dependiendo si es verdadero o falso un estado.

Lo estoy realizando con un case.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```html
SELECT 
A.Currency_Code as 'Moneda',
B.Supplier_Code as 'Alias del Beneficiario',
B.Name as 'Nombre del Beneficiario',
B.Bank_Name as 'Nombre Banco Beneficiario',

Case
WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'False' THEN SUM(A.Amount) 
WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'True' THEN A.Amount
 END as 'Monto del Pago',

B.Bank_Account_No as 'Cuenta del Beneficiario'
--CONCAT (B.Supplier_Code,' ',A.Invoice_No) AS 'Concepto de Pago'
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_e A
LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_e B ON A.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_Accounting_e C ON C.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
WHERE A.Paid = '1' AND A.Currency_Code = 'MXN' AND Convert(DATE,A.Paid_Date) Between @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin
GROUP BY A.Currency_Code,B.Supplier_Code,B.Name,B.Bank_Name,B.Bank_Account_No,C.Payment_Per_Invoice,A.Amount,A.Invoice_No
ORDER BY B.Supplier_Code
```

No me está sumando pero quisiera que me dieran su opinión de si esta sería la forma correcta de realizar este query o existe alguna otra forma de llegar al resultado que me solicitan.

Comment: Qué tiene que ver datatables y jquery-validate?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es aplicar la suma, pero englobando el case.

Ejemplo

```
sum(CASE WHEN validacion='TRUE' THEN valor ELSE 0 END)
```

Esto lo que hará es que cuando tu condición se cumpla regresa el valor y lo aplicara en la suma, caso contrario regresa 0 y no afecta tu suma.

Y esto aplicado a tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT 
    A.Currency_Code as 'Moneda',
    B.Supplier_Code as 'Alias del Beneficiario',
    B.Name as 'Nombre del Beneficiario',
    B.Bank_Name as 'Nombre Banco Beneficiario',
    /*
        Aquí es solo validar si suma cuando es true o cuando es false,
        O si sumara otra cosa en caso de que no aplique la condición
    */
    sum(Case WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'False' THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END) as 'Monto del Pago',
    B.Bank_Account_No as 'Cuenta del Beneficiario'
    --CONCAT (B.Supplier_Code,' ',A.Invoice_No) AS 'Concepto de Pago'
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_e A
    LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_e B ON A.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
    LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_Accounting_e C ON C.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
WHERE A.Paid = '1'
    AND A.Currency_Code = 'MXN'
    AND Convert(DATE,A.Paid_Date) Between @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin
GROUP BY A.Currency_Code, B.Supplier_Code, B.Name, B.Bank_Name, B.Bank_Account_No, C.Payment_Per_Invoice, A.Amount,A.Invoice_No
ORDER BY B.Supplier_Code
```

En base a el comentario de agrupar solo los true, lo único que se me ocurre es agregar otra columna donde se valide la condición de el invoce y en base a eso hacer el agrupado de la cantidad.

```
SELECT 
    A.Currency_Code as 'Moneda',
    B.Supplier_Code as 'Alias del Beneficiario',
    B.Name as 'Nombre del Beneficiario',
    B.Bank_Name as 'Nombre Banco Beneficiario',
    /*
        Aquí es solo validar si suma cuando es true o cuando es false,
        O si sumara otra cosa en caso de que no aplique la condición
    */
    sum(Case WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'False' THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END) as 'Monto del Pago',
    B.Bank_Account_No as 'Cuenta del Beneficiario',
    --CONCAT (B.Supplier_Code,' ',A.Invoice_No) AS 'Concepto de Pago',
    /*
        Solo te regresara un valor cuando el estatus sea 1, por lo que todos los invoice en 1 te los desagrupara y los que esten inactivos regresara 0 y te los agrupara
    */
    CASE WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 1 THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END Amount2
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_e A
    LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_e B ON A.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
    LEFT JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_Accounting_e C ON C.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
WHERE A.Paid = '1'
    AND A.Currency_Code = 'MXN'
    AND Convert(DATE,A.Paid_Date) Between @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin
GROUP BY A.Currency_Code, B.Supplier_Code, B.Name, B.Bank_Name, B.Bank_Account_No, C.Payment_Per_Invoice, A.Amount,A.Invoice_No,
CASE WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 1 THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END Amount2
ORDER BY B.Supplier_Code
```

Comment: muchas gracias. solo que asi solo me suma pero también tengo datos que no quiero que sume, esto si esta en un estatus 'true'

Comment: no es posible tener ese campo con suma y sin suma, puedes agregarlo dentro de tu Select en otra columna, pero tienen que coincidir sus valores de lo contrario no aplicara la suma en ningún registro y no funcionara el agrupado

Comment: solo que si lo coloco en otra columna me desagrupa la suma, básicamente me da el mismo resultado

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es agregar la columna en un case adicional y validar el invoce para determinar si lo agrupas o lo desagrupas, algo asl `, CASE WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 1 THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END Amount2. y ese mismo agrégalo al group y te debe agrupar solo los falsos